# Replace double quotes with nothing, triple double qoutes with double qotes

Tags: c#, regex, double-quotes

I would like to replace single double quotes with string.Empty, and triple double quotes with double quotes like this:

```
"StackOverflow"    --->    StackOverflow
"""StackOverflow"   --->   "StackOverflow"
```

I would like to note that source text would contain only double quotes or triple double quotes, other case doesn't matter.

**UPDATE:**

Assume we have such input text:

```
"StackOverflow"
"""StackOverflow"""
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
StackOverflow
"StackOverflow"
```

I know I can't do this with pure C# code (without some dirty codes) because I need to detect where exactly single double quotes is, and where multiple occurences of double quotes are. I think it can be done only with regex, all my tries like this failed:

```
[\"]{1}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Sorry but `I would like to` is not a question. You explained your requirements, now what is the problem?

Comment: Are there any characters (from the *whole* of Unicode) that you can safely assume will not appear in your string? If so, replace the triples with that character, strip any remaining quotes, replace that character with double quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't `"""StackOverflow"` turn into `"StackOverflow` by your logic? It ends in a single double quote. It looks more like you're trying to parse `@""` style escaped strings where you want to strip the *outer* double quotes, then de-duplicate any doubled up quotes in that string.

Comment: Some form of regex replace can likely help you no matter the exact scenario. Use (e.g.) `"\"{3}"` to match exactly three quotes, and `"\"(?!\")"` to match a quote only when it is not followed by another quote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex, which matches either case and replaces it with appropriately captured group text. Match this regex

```
(")""|"
```

and replace it with \1

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCcPUj/2)

Let me know if this works fine for you.